# Compare two columns with no header of same csv file and output matching values using Python 3.8

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with two columns with no header. I want to compare these two columns and find out if column one matches with the list of column 2 and extract the matching values into a new CSV file (output.csv), and delete the whole row if column 2 does not have matching values with column 1.  For example,

**Input.csv:**

```
1,"[0, 10, 12, 13, 16, 25, 32, 35, 60, 86, 98, 108, 168, 172, 222, 251, 275, 278, 325, 365]"
60,"[12014, 25665, 28278]"
86,"[0, 6, 7, 10, 12, 25, 76, 156, 174, 176, 181, 188, 365, 392, 438]"
108,"[1, 16, 21, 32, 35, 61, 81, 83, 95, 138, 153, 204, 222]"
438,"[30549]"
28278,"[60, 120, 140, 505, 3939, 4034, 7213, 7308, 8784, 14126, 14147, 15197, 16842, 20022, 28229]"
```

**output.csv:**

```
1,"[60, 108]"
60,"[28278]"
108,"[1]"
28278,"[60]"
```

I have tried this code,

```
    import csv

    with open('input.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')

    nodes_in_1 = set()
    nodes_in_2 = set()

    for line in csvreader:
        nodes_in_1.add(line[0])
        nodes_in_2.add(line[1])

    nodes_in_both = nodes_in_1.intersection(nodes_in_2)

    with open('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(nodes_in_both + '\n')
```

I am a beginner. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: This is not a hard problem.  What have you done so far?  You will need to process the file twice.  First pass, you gather the contents of column 1.  Second pass, you filter based on column 2.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have tried that code, but it does not work. I have tried to work with Pandas, which I have read is easier, but I have not been able to find a way to compare to the second column, as I get an empty output file or inverted columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can indeed be done in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",header=None, converters={1: literal_eval}) # load csv, use literal_eval to load the lists as lists in stead of strings
df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in df[0].tolist()]) # keep only the values in the lists in the second column that match with a value in the first column
df = df[df[1].map(len) > 0] # drop rows with empty lists  
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None) # write df to csv
```

Output df:

```
|    |     0 | 1             |
|---:|------:|:--------------|
|  0 |     1 | [60, 86, 108] |
|  1 |    60 | [28278]       |
|  2 |    86 | [438]         |
|  3 |   108 | [1]           |
|  5 | 28278 | [60]          |
```

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def run():
    c1,c3 = [],[]
    with open('stack1.txt') as f:
        # c1 holds 1st column values
        for line in f:
            c1.append(line.split(',')[0].replace(' ',''))
        f.seek(0)
        for line in f:
            cx = line.split(',')[0].replace(' ','')
            # get list stored in column 2
            c2 = re.search('\[.*\]', line).group()[1:-1].replace(' ','').split(',')
            # find elements common with c1 (first column)
            c2 = [i for i in c2 if i in c1] 
            if c2:
                c3.append(cx + ',"[{}]"'.format(','.join(c2)))
    with open('stack1.out','w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(c3))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Above code does what you want to do. I hope I am not abusing your class homework ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the help.